# Duplicate elements while fetching comments from Database

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, nuxt.js

I was implementing Pagination (Django Rest Framework - PageNumberPagination) recently. But, I quickly ran into an issue. Can you help?

```
comments_list = CommentModel.objects.filter(blog=blog).order_by('-createdAt')
```

TL;DR; =>
Given,
I have written a post & multiple People can add comments
When,
They write a comment
Then,
How can I make sure that, I'm not displaying duplicated result?

Current Implementation of Pagination:
API: "Each Page contains N number of items. Tell me what page number do you want?"
`path/to/api/?page=N`

Frontend: "Starts with Page = 1 and upon a successful response, increments it by One."

Explanation:
say these are my comments
 `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`

I want to show them in Latest -> Oldest
`[11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

In each page there are N = 10 numbers of Results.
`[11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2,    |   1]`
where, "|" => page 1.

I add a new Comment **C1**

Hence the the backend Array becomes => `[C1, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

and the split becomes => `[C1, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3,     |    2, 1]`

But, my frontend doesn't know it yet, hence when it requests for page 2,

the list becomes => `[C1, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2] + [2, 1] => [C1, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2 ,1]`

Therefore, Creating a Duplicate entry being displayed in frontend.

(upon refresh this goes away, until someone else chooses to add a comment in the meanwhile)

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: can you show us the queryset you are using ?

Comment: comments_list = CommentModel.objects.filter(blog=blog).order_by('-createdAt')

Comment: is there a possibility to be createAt values for to CommentModel instances are same?

Answer (score 0):

`Cursor Pagination` is the Key Here.